# Trocar caracteres dentro de uma string, em uma string

Tags: c#, .net, string, regex, visual-basic-6

Simples a pergunta: Quero apenas substituir os caracteres `A` dentro do campo `" "` e não o que estiver fora por um B, exemplo:

```
aaaaaaaaaa"aaaa"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa"aaaaaaaaaa"aaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

fique assim:

```
aaaaaaaaaa"bbbb"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa"bbbbbbbbbb"aaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Aceito respostas em C# e VB, até usando Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `regex`, da seguinte maneira:

**C#**

```
string original = @"aaaaaaaaaa""aaaa""aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa""aaaaaaaaaa""aaaaaaaaaaaaa";

// percorre todas os valores que estejam entre aspas duplas
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(original, @"\""+[A-z].*?\""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    // pega o valor encontrado e remove as aspas
    string valorEncontrado = match.Value.Replace("\"", String.Empty);
    // cria uma nova string do tamanho do valor encontrado
    string novoValor = new String('b', valorEncontrado.Length);
    // substitui o valor original pela nova string, re-adicionando as aspas
    original = original.Replace(match.Value, "\"" + novoValor + "\"");
}
```

**VB**

```
Dim original As String = "aaaaaaaaaa""aaaa""aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa""aaaaaaaaaa""aaaaaaaaaaaaa"

For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(original, """[A-z].*?""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim valorEncontrado As String = match.Value.Replace("""", String.Empty)     
    Dim novoValor As String = New String("b"c, valorEncontrado.Length)
    original = original.Replace(match.Value, """" + novoValor + """")
Next
```

Veja funcionando [aqui em C#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gFwSWt) e [aqui em VB](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1BOoLx).

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi responder porque as soluções são bastante ineficientes fazendo alocações sem necessidade e operações repetitivas. A resposta aceita sequer funciona conforme está determinado na pergunta.

Eu ainda melhorei algo que a pergunta não fala quando as aspas são abertas e não fechadas ne mesma linha. Considerei que o fim da linha encerra o texto "citado".

Não criei uma função porque parece ser algo muito específico, mas poderia generalizar isso para receber quaisquer caracteres, escolher um que deve ser trocado e para qual será trocado. Pode-se fazer até mesmo uma lista de caracteres que devem ser trocados por seus respectivos novos caracteres.

```
var text = "aaaaaaaaaa\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaa\"aaaaaaaaaa\"aaaaaaaaaaaaa";
var open = false;
System.Text.StringBuilder newText = new();
foreach (var character in text) {
    if (character == '"' || (open && character == '\n')) {
        open = !open;
        newText.Append(character);
    } else newText.Append(open ? 'b' : character);
}
System.Console.WriteLine(newText);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sfgoSQ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nnkg0E). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ChangeQuoted.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode usar este código:

```
string a = "aaaaaaaaaa\"aaa\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaa\"aaaaaaaaaa\"aaaaaaaaaaaaa";
string[] nova = a.Split('"');
for (int i = 0; i < nova.Length; i++)
{
    if (i==1 || i%3==0)
    {
        int x = nova[i].Length;
        StringBuilder k = new StringBuilder();
        for (int v = 0; v < x; v++)
        {
            k.Append("b");
        }
        nova[i] = '"'+k.ToString()+'"';
    }
}
string novastring;
foreach (var item in nova)
{
    novastring += item.ToString();
}
```

Comment: O [seu código](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DauWLA) está retornando `"bbbbbbbbbb""bbb"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa"bbbbbbbbbb"aaaaaaaaaaaaa`

Comment: if (i==1 || i%3==0 && i != 0)

Comment: altera a declaração if, deixa ela assim

Comment: Também recomendo evitar o máximo possível o regex, porque é muito complicado.

Answer (score 1):

Os caracteres `"` no meio da string não são aceitos da forma que está na pergunta. Para adicionar um " no meio de uma string deverá ser:

- substituir por `\"`
- adicionar `@` no começo da string e substiruir por `""`
- substituir pela caractere ASCII por `'\u0022'`

Segue o código em c#:

```
List<string> listaOriginal = new List<string>();
List<string> listaFinal = new List<string>();

listaOriginal.Add("aaaaaaaaaa\"aaaa\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
listaOriginal.Add("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
listaOriginal.Add("aaaaa\"aaaaaaaaaa\"aaaaaaaaaaaaa");

foreach (string original in listaOriginal)
{
    StringBuilder final = new StringBuilder();

    string[] split = original.Split('\"');

    final.Append(split[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            string s = split[i].Replace("a", "b");
            split[i] = s;
        }

        final.Append("\"" + split[i]);
    }

    listaFinal.Add(final.ToString());
}
```

Saída:

```
listaFinal
Count = 3
[0]: "aaaaaaaaaa\"bbbb\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
[1]: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
[2]: "aaaaa\"bbbbbbbbbb\"aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

[Referência MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa983682(v=vs.71).aspx)